# How to install and Implement the HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp in Azure Webapp (api)

Tags: nuget

Our development team implemented Pdfsharp in order to generate the pdf at website

they installed the pdfsharp package in a local environment with using this command at VisualStudio "Install-Package HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp -Version 1.5.0.5" it working fine

comes to production environment code is deployed through Azure DevOps CI/CD 
when the build process creation we are implemented Nuget, NPM, and other steps.
now we added same line command in with .Net-CLI " add package HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp --version 1.5.0.5"-----> when I doing like it through the error message 
Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects :

I tried to install a pdfsharp package directly in webapp  (API) using PowerShell
but I don't have an idea about installing the pdfshap in backend server level is it the right way or not is still ??

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [overview on how to use packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/overview-and-workflow).

In short, you only install/add the package to the project once. This modifies the project, and you save the modified `csproj` into source control. Then on the CI machine, you run `dotnet restore` on your solution (if your solution contains only SDK style projects, `nuget restore` otherwise).

And for future reference, telling us that dotnet.exe returned exit code 1 is insufficient to understand the problem. dotnet.exe's output will contain additional error information about why it failed.

Comment: Thanks for your information, ill update remaining full detailed error message